# Bug/Error with KMeans (and BisectingKMeans) clustering

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, apache-spark-mllib

I'm working on a data where I'm required to work with clusters.

I know the Spark framework won't let me have one single cluster; the minimum number of clusters is  two.

I created some dummy random data to test my program, and my program is displaying wrong results because my KMeans function is generating ONE cluster! How come? I don't understand. Is it because my data is random? I have not specified anything on my kmeans. This is the part of the code that handles the K-Means:

```
kmeans = new BisectingKMeans();
model = kmeans.fit(dataset); //trains the k-means with the dataset to create a model

clusterCenters = model.clusterCenters(); 

dataset.show(false);

for(Vector v : clusterCenters){
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

The output is the following:

```
+----+----+------+
|File|Size|Volume|
+----+----+------+
|F1  |13  |1689  |
|F2  |18  |1906  |
|F3  |16  |1829  |
|F4  |14  |1726  |
|F5  |10  |1524  |
|F6  |16  |1844  |
|F7  |15  |1752  |
|F8  |12  |1610  |
|F9  |10  |1510  |
|F10 |11  |1554  |
|F11 |12  |1632  |
|F12 |13  |1663  |
|F13 |18  |1901  |
|F14 |13  |1686  |
|F15 |18  |1910  |
|F16 |19  |1986  |
|F17 |11  |1585  |
|F18 |10  |1500  |
|F19 |13  |1665  |
|F20 |13  |1664  |
+----+----+------+
only showing top 20 rows

[-1.7541523789077474E-16,2.0655699373151038E-15] //only one cluster center!!! why??
```

Why does this happen? What do I need to fix to solve this? Having only one cluster ruins my program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On random data, the *correct* output of bisecting k-means often is a single cluster only.

With bisecting k-means you only give a *maximum* number of clusters. But it can stop early, if the results do not improve. In you case, splitting the data into two clusters apparently did not improve the quality, so this bisection is not accepted.

Comment: Ah okay I understand! So random data does severely affect my model. With normal, real data this behavior shouldn't happen, correct? I would hope so at least. In any case, thanks for explaining it to me.

Comment: With ideal data, it wouldn't. But if the data only has one cluster, is badly preprocessed, or very noisy, then you may see a single cluster also on real data. You will be surprised how often you won't find meaningful clusters with a method like k-means...